# Save Tweets as .csv, Contains String Literals and Entities

Tags: python-3.x, csv, text, twitter, string-literals

I have tweets saved in JSON text files.  I have a friend who wants tweets containing keywords, and the tweets need to be saved in a .csv.  Finding the tweets is easy, but I run into two problems and am struggling with finding a good solution.

Sample data are [here](https://github.com/ZacharyST/Data/tree/master/Twitter_SaveCSV).  I have included the .csv file that is not working as well as a file where each row is a tweet in JSON format.

To get into a dataframe, I use `pd.io.json.json_normalize`.  It works smoothly and handles nested dictionaries well, but `pd.to_csv` does not work because it does not handle, as far as I can tell, string literals well.  Some of the tweets contain `'\n'` in the `text` field, and `pandas` writes new lines when that happens.

No problem, I process `pd['text']` to remove `'\n'`.  The resulting file still has too many rows, 1863 compared to the 1388 it should.  I then modified my code to replace all string-literals:

```
tweets['text'] = [item.replace('\n', '') for item in tweets['text']]
tweets['text'] = [item.replace('\r', '') for item in tweets['text']]
tweets['text'] = [item.replace('\\', '') for item in tweets['text']]
tweets['text'] = [item.replace('\'', '') for item in tweets['text']]
tweets['text'] = [item.replace('\"', '') for item in tweets['text']]
tweets['text'] = [item.replace('\a', '') for item in tweets['text']]
tweets['text'] = [item.replace('\b', '') for item in tweets['text']]
tweets['text'] = [item.replace('\f', '') for item in tweets['text']]
tweets['text'] = [item.replace('\t', '') for item in tweets['text']]
tweets['text'] = [item.replace('\v', '') for item in tweets['text']]
```

Same result, `pd.to_csv` saves a file with more rows than actual tweets.  I could replace string literals in all columns, but that is clunky.

Fine, don't use `pandas`.  `with open(outpath, 'w') as f:` and so on creates a .csv file with the correct number of rows.  Reading the file, either with `pd.read_csv` or reading line by line will fail, however.

It fails because of how Twitter handles [entities](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects).  If a tweet's text contains a url, mention, hashtag, media, or link, then Twitter returns a dictionary that contains commas.  When `pandas` flattens the tweet, the commas get preserved within a column, which is good.  But when the data are read in, pandas splits what should be one column into multiple columns.  For example, a column might look like  `[{'screen_name': 'ProfOsinbajo','name': 'Prof Yemi Osinbajo','id': 2914442873,'id_str': '2914442873', 'indices': [0,' 13]}]'`, so splitting on commas creates too many columns:

```
 [{'screen_name': 'ProfOsinbajo',
 'name': 'Prof Yemi Osinbajo',
 'id': 2914442873",
 'id_str': '2914442873'",
 'indices': [0,
 13]}]
```

That is the outcome whether I use `with open(outpath) as f:` as well.  With that approach, I have to split lines, so I split on commas.  Same problem - I do not want to split on commas if they occur in a list.

**I want those data to be treated as one column when saved to file or read from file.  What am I missing?**  In terms of the data at [the repository above](https://github.com/ZacharyST/Data/tree/master/Twitter_SaveCSV), I want to convert `forstackoverflow2.txt` to a .csv with as many rows as tweets.  Call this file `A.csv`, and let's say it has 100 columns. When opened, `A.csv` should also have 100 columns.

I'm sure there are details I've left out, so please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `csv` module works.  It writes the file out as a .csv while counting the lines, then reads it back in and counts the lines again.

The result matched, and opening the .csv in Excel also gives 191 columns and 1338 lines of data.

```
import json
import csv

with open('forstackoverflow2.txt') as f,\
     open('out.csv','w',encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as out:
    data = json.loads(next(f))
    print('columns',len(data))
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out,fieldnames=sorted(data))
    writer.writeheader() # write header
    writer.writerow(data) # write the first line of data
    for i,line in enumerate(f,2): # start line count at two
        data = json.loads(line)
        writer.writerow(data)
    print('lines',i)

with open('out.csv',encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.DictReader(f)
    lines = list(r)
    print('readback columns',len(lines[0]))
    print('readback lines',len(lines))
```

Output:

```
columns 191
lines 1338
readback lines 1338
readback columns 191
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mark Tolonen's answer is helpful, but I ended up going a separate route.  When saving the tweets to file, I removed all `\r`, `\n`, `\t`, and `\0` characters from anywhere in the JSON.  Then, I save the file with as tab separated so that commas in fields like `location` or `text` do not confuse a `read` function.

Comment: The csv module quotes fields and escapes the quote character within the field, so you shouldn't have to pre-process the JSON or use tab-delimited fields since the commas would be in quoted fields.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I couldn't figure out any better reason I couldn't get my code to work.  Perhaps it was moving the literal-strings that did it.  Also, I didn't try ```csv``` so maybe I should have.  I am doing this for a friend who doesn't use Python, so I wanted to avoid that solution.